# PHP string offset? Using a variable like a buffer when doing many substr is too slow?

Tags: php, pointers, substr

I have a buffer that need to be interpreted by PHP, however using many substr subsequently on the buffer proved to be very slow and cpu intensive, likely because substr create a new copy of the substring.

I need to move forward in a buffer by:

moving by an offset of X (variable number of bytes).
or 
removing X bytes from the beginning

Are there any container in PHP that would let me do something like that?

Exemple (Pseudocode)

```
while( !done )
{
   $itemSize = unpack( ?, $buffer );
   $item = substr($buffer, $itemSize );
   $done = doSomething( $item );
   $buffer = $item;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `while( !done )` gives syntax error.

Comment: @Jeffery - And `unpack( ?` is invalid as well.  I'm pretty sure it's just pseudocode.

Comment: Yes this is correct, I should have specified this is just a pseudocode example.

Comment: If it can be loaded into memory, or temp files are fast enough, you could try `fread` with the `php://memory` or `php://temp` streams. Not sure if it's faster, but worth a try.

Comment: I will look into that suggestion, I've also though about array but found out that: PHP uses hash tables to implement arrays, i.e. in order to access an element in an array it has to calculate a hash and traverse a linked list, worst case I could always call to C code from php, but I will leave that as last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Working at byte level is really not what PHP is created for. How PHP manages the memory is way more complex than what you think. It works with a lot of references and very few copies are made even if you don't use `&`.

I highly doubt the slowness came from doing many `substr` and I highly doubt that managing the memory at byte level with PHP would be of any help in that.

Comment: We have run a profiler on the code and it's indeed substr that is very slow, here is someone else with a similar issue: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7220/php-substr-slow